# Java Jackson ObjectMapper - Annotation for taking an object as is without digging deeper

Tags: java, jackson

I have a simple POJO class looking like this:

```
public class EventPOJO {

    public EventPOJO() {
    }


    public String id, title;
    // Looking for an annotation here
    public Timestamp startDate, endDate;
}
```

This is how I create a Map using `ObjectMapper`:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 Map<String, Object> event = mapper.convertValue(myPOJO, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

I need mapper to contain the **key** `"startDate"` with the **value** of Type `Timestamp`.
(com.google.firebase.Timestamp)

Instead however mapper contains the **key** `"startDate"` with the **value** of Type `LinkedHashMap` containing the nanoseconds and seconds.

So basically I need the mapper to stop when seeing an object of type Timestamp and put it in the map as is.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the annotation JsonIgnore?

Comment: @Edgar Yes. That way the timestamps won't appear at all inside the map.

Comment: You are right. Maybe you can do it by creating a custom serializer.